# Google authentication from server

Tags: java, youtube-api, google-oauth

I am need to upload video to youtube to specific youtube account. So I need to authenticate I am using java google lib. Code looks like this:

```
          Credential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(new ApacheHttpTransport())
            .setJsonFactory(new JacksonFactory())
            .setServiceAccountId("xxx@xx-app.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
            .setClientSecrets("xx@gmail.com", "xx")
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("xx.p12"))
            .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes)
            .setServiceAccountUser("xx@gmail.com")
            .build();

          youtube = new YouTube.Builder(credential.getTransport(), credential.getJsonFactory(), credential).setApplicationName(
            "tellews-app").build();
          Video returnedVideo = videoInsert.execute();
          YouTube.Videos.Insert videoInsert = youtube.videos()
            .insert("snippet,statistics,status", videoObjectDefiningMetadata, mediaContent);
          Video returnedVideo = videoInsert.execute();
```

And getting error:

`IOException: 401 Unauthorized
{
  "error" : "unauthorized_client",
  "error_description" : "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method."
}`

Maybe someone sees what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

**Do not use a Service Account - that's not what they're there for.**

You need to obtain an Access Token for the target YouTube account. The simples way to do that is to get yourself a Refresh Token for that account from the Oauth Playground, and use it to fetch an Access Token whenever you need one. The steps to do this are enumerated at [How do I authorise an app (web or installed) without user intervention? (canonical ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention-canonic) . In the comments there is a link to a YouTube video which also explains the steps.